# Can cookies help hacker to access our activites?

Tags: cookies

I have read about cookies of browsers. I read that cookies can store our browser's history. Whatever we have searched and whatever we have watched all kind of activities storied in cookies. I also read that every website has its own cookies files and when we search any thing on a website so it drops a cookie file in our computer .

---

I have read about cookies for here in hindi (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-0Kaj1RIXc)

- Are cookies dangerous for security.
- Can cookies help hackers to access our activities.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding on how cookies work. Cookies are created for a single person when they visit that website. They are meant to store information so the website knows it's the same user the next time they visit. This has been abused by some advertisers who embed ads on many websites, thus can set and read their own cookies for many webpages where they have ads/trackers embedded. They simply keep a record of every URL they see your unique cookie identifier. It gets more in depth, but there's many ways companies can track your activities other than cookies.

Comment: This question lacks research. Clicking on the `cookies` tag will bring up a lot of resources for you to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think on cookies like cards that were given to you in eg. a mall.

- You start in shop A and they give you a discount card with your purchase for your next visit.
- As soon as you enter in shop B you are given a card with a discount "if used today".
- When you go for a drink, you are given a card with benefits in shop D.

(all these cards are used for tracking you, but not actually "dangerous")

Plus, there are other cards being used by the personnel:

- The cashiers use an employee card open the register
- You need a special card to enter the locker room
- Or for opening your locker

Not to mention the credit cards used to pay for the operations, or in the ATM.

As you see, these cards can serve for many multiple purposes. They may store a discount, be used to remember that last time you bought X (in order to advertise you more or them), or note that you are allowed into a special room.

Cookies are like these cards, not *dangerous* per se (other than for your privacy, maybe), nor do they allow access to your activities (whatever they are) since the right card. However, having access to the cookies of a different user could allow access to places that were not intended to that person, but to the original user.